# Queries slow when run by specific Windows account

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

Running `SQL Server 2014 Express` on our domain. We use `Windows Authentication` to log on. All queries are performed in stored procedures.

Now, the system runs fine for all our users - except one. When he logs on (using our software), all queries take around 10 times longer (e.g. 30 ms instead of 2 ms). The queries are identical, the database is the same, the network speed is the same, the operative system is the same, the SQL Server drivers are the same, connection pooling is the same, DNS is the same. Changing computer does not help. The problem seems to be linked to the account being used.

What on Earth may be the cause for this huge performance hit?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try rebuilding the SP (by running an ALTER statement that duplicates its existing structure) to force SQL Server to recompile. I don't know every way SQL Server caches things but it can definitely create distinct execution plans for different types of connections so I wouldn't be surprised if your slow user is running a version with an inefficient execution plan.

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Thanks. I just ran `EXEC sp_updatestats` but that did not help (even though some warnings disappeared from the execution plans).

Comment: Turned out to be a problem with the VS debugger (forgot to mention that). This answer would most likely have been correct otherwise :)